# allowed limited/fix numbers of records/rows of csv upload in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv, file-upload

I am allowing users to upload their email contact csv. also I am Inserting it in mysql. I want to make sure user only upload csv that contain 1500 records or 5000 records or what I let them to upload.

My controller file csv.php is contain following code. I tried `$config['max_size'] = 1000;`
can anyone help me out please...

```
<?php

    class Csv extends CI_Controller {


    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index() {
        $data = array('title' => 'Upload CSV Contacts');
        $this->load->view('csvupload_view', $data);
    }

    function import_csv() {

        $data['error'] = '';    //initialize image upload error array to empty

        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/extra/member_upload/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);


        // If upload failed, display error
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
            $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
            $this->load->view('csvupload_view', $data);
        } else {
            $file_data = $this->upload->data();
            $file_path =  './assets/extra/member_upload/'.$file_data['file_name'];

            if ($this->csvimport->get_array($file_path)) {
                $csv_array = $this->csvimport->get_array($file_path);

                $this->load->model('csv_model');
                //convert array of arrays into array
                foreach($csv_array as $key=>$val)
                {
                    $csv_array[$key] = array('email' => $val['Email'], 'name' => $val['Name']); //EMAIL & NAME is case sensitive
                    $this->csv_model->insert_csv($csv_array[$key]); //call model to insert data in DB
                }

            } else 
                $data['error'] = "Error occured";
                $this->load->view('csvupload_view', $data);
            }

        } 

}
?>
```

Comment: `$config['max_size']` sets the file size in kilobytes and so isn't going to be helpful. In order to limit the number of entries you're probably going to have to read the file line by line until the max entries count is reached.

Comment: @DFriend thanks for it, I didn't know that. do you know how to read it line by line. please help me.